# Receiving notifications from default notification center while app in background

Tags: ios, swift, background-process, notificationcenter, camera-roll

In my app, I'm fetching the content of camera-roll with `fetchAssets(with:)`. To receive change messages, I've registered my observer with the photo library’s `register(_:)` method. My observer is comforting to the `PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver` protocol. So when the library is changing, I should get notified about that. The scenario I want to support is while I'm running my app, I go to background, then open the camera app, take a picture, then go back to my app. Is it possible to get the notification of a change that occurred while my app was in background, when it comes back to foreground?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create LocalNotificaion and trigger it when app is going in background and coming back in foreground.

```
func scheduleNotification(timeInter : TimeInterval) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        let userActions = "User Actions"
        content.title = "Title "
        content.body = "Body"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: 
        content.categoryIdentifier = userActions
        content.userInfo = ["MID" : RANDOM_ID, "timeInterval" : String(timeInter)]
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: timeInter, repeats: false)
        let identifier = String(timeInter)


        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        print(request.identifier)
        notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
            if let error = error {

            }
        }
        //  let snoozeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "Snooze", title: "Snooze", options: [])
        let deleteAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "Delete", title: "Delete", options: [.destructive])
        let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: userActions, actions: [deleteAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
        notificationCenter.setNotificationCategories([category])
    }
```

Comment: Should I ask for user permission for that?